# How can I edit the razor pages in the ASP.NET Core (3.1) with Angular and Individual Accounts Authentication type?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authentication, razor

I created a project in Visual Studio 2022 using this template:

[image]

[image]

The template starts me off with functioning login and register pages:

[image]

How can I edit these pages to do things like add buttons and change colors?

Note that in this template, there is no areas folder, all I have is the following:

[image]

I have tried adding scaffolding and I get this error:
[image]
[image]

I would also really welcome any recommendations for tutorials for learning razor pages and using them with angular!

Comment: The package conflicts with the project's version, or with other packages, SO you need check in your xxx.csproj file to  see if there are any conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Per [@Xinran-Shen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17438579/xinran-shen)'s comment, I changed almost all my packages to the same version.

I had one package that didn't have that version, so I left that as is.

The ItemGroup section in my .CSProj file now looks like this:
[image]

Additionally, for this ASP.NET Core (3.1) with Angular and Individual Accounts Authentication type Configuration/setup, when you add an identity, you must leave this blank:
[image]